# ASM In c++ project ...How this little asm code will be in c++

Tags: c++, assembly

Hellow I found an asm code ... which was integrated in c++ project

```
template <class T>
T returned; 

BYTE *tem = buffer;
__asm
{
    mov eax, tem
    call eax
    mov  returned, eax
}
```

So As I don´t know asm It is hard To understood what this code  means ...
Can anyone convert this ASM code in c++ entirely and post here :) 
Ttanks...

Answer (score 8):

It looks like it is executing code placed in a buffer and returning the contents of the EAX register. You might try this:

```
typedef T (*pfn)();

returned = ((pfn) buffer)();
```

Comment: Surely you mean `typedef T (*pfn)()`?

Answer (score 3):

The assembly code is essentially treating tem as a function pointer and calling it. It is then putting the return into returned.

Answer (score 3):

```
mov eax, tem;
```

The contents of `tem` is transferrer into the processor internal register `eax`

```
call eax
```

The contents of `eax` is used to make a function call. The code starting at the address which `eax` holds will be executed. After the function call returns the return value will be in the register `eax`

```
mov returned, eax
```

The return value in `eax` is transferred into a variable `returned`

This is what basically the code does. You shold have a look at the `call` instuction to know how exactly it works.